# For Loop - Get Element by Id

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a for loop that is equivalent to the the code below that way I don't have to type it all out each time.

```
var q1 = document.getElementById("q1").value;
var q2 = document.getElementById("q2").value;
var q3 = document.getElementById("q3").value;
var q4 = document.getElementById("q4").value;
var q5 = document.getElementById("q5").value;
google.script.run.AddRecord(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5);
```

I am particularly having a hard time declaring qi where i=1, 2, .., 5, so that way it doesn't think it's just a word or array. I have tried different things using string concatenation but can't get it to work (see started loop below). I feel like I am missing one little thing which is causing it to run into issues. I have seen different questions about this but can't get it to work.

```
for(var i=1; i<=5; ++i){
var "q"+i=document.getElementById("q"+i).value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the values into an array and then use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to pass them to `google.script.run.AddRecord`

```js
const elements = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    elements.push(document.getElementById(`q${i}`).value);
}

google.script.run.AddRecord(...elements);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array for this purpose. Declare an array and use i as an index to insert values in the array.

```
var markers = [];

for(var i=1; i<=5; ++i){
  markers[i] = document.getElementById("q"+i).value;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer! I would use this. Remember arrays have been creating to handle sets of data. So if you want to access q1 its now markers[1].

Comment: Exactly it will be accessible by array index like markers[0], markers[1], etc